# FactoryGirl, why I get already registered or uninitialized constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, tdd, factory-bot

I am trying to do a simple test for my model `Course`, I have wrote this factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    name 'How to be happy ?'
    end
end
```

the course_spec.rb:

```
require "rspec"
require 'factory_girl_rails'
describe "When a course is created" do

  it "can't be deleted if any student is enrolled to it" do
    FactoryGirl.find_definitions
    course = FactoryGirl.build(:course)

    student= Student.create!
    course.students << student
    course.destroy
    course.name.should !=nil
  end
end
```

but, I reach this line

```
course = FactoryGirl.build(:course)
```

I get the error:

```
FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError: Factory already registered: course
```

if I comment the :course definition in the factory, I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Course
```

Any idea please ?

here is my Gem Envioronment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86-linux
GEM PATHS:
   /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
   /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global
GEM CONFIGURATION:
   :update_sources => true
   :verbose => true
   :benchmark => false
   :backtrace => false
   :bulk_threshold => 1000
REMOTE SOURCES:
   http://rubygems.org/
----------------------
IDE: JetBrains RubyMine (EAP) RM-112.291, build #RM-112.291
OS: Linux 3.0.0-12-generic[i386]
Java: 1.6.0_23-b23
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: RVM: ruby-1.9.3-p0
Sdk Version: ver.1.9.3p0 ( revision 33570) p0
Ruby Interpreter: /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
RVM Sdk: yes, gemset:[default]
RVM Home: /home/sam/.rvm
Sdk Language Level: 1.9
Sdk Load Path:
     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby
     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1
     /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     /home/sam/rubyMine4beta/rubystubs19
Sdk Gem paths: 
     file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems
     file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems
     file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems
Gems used for 'hope':
     ffi (1.0.11, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ffi-1.0.11)
     sass (3.1.12, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sass-3.1.12)
     coffee-script-source (1.2.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-script-source-1.2.0)
     mail (2.3.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mail-2.3.0)
     activesupport (3.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.0)
     i18n (0.6.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/i18n-0.6.0)
     uglifier (1.2.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/uglifier-1.2.1)
     sprockets (2.0.3, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sprockets-2.0.3)
     foreigner (1.1.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/foreigner-1.1.1)
     treetop (1.4.10, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/treetop-1.4.10)
     haml (3.1.4, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/haml-3.1.4)
     ansi (1.4.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ansi-1.4.1)
     mime-types (1.17.2, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mime-types-1.17.2)
     rack (1.3.6, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.3.6)
     devise (1.5.2, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/devise-1.5.2)
     warden (1.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/warden-1.1.0)
     diff-lcs (1.1.3, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.3)
     activeresource (3.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activeresource-3.1.0)
     sass-rails (3.1.5, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sass-rails-3.1.5)
     therubyracer (0.9.9, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/therubyracer-0.9.9)
     rspec-expectations (2.7.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-expectations-2.7.0)
     coffee-rails (3.1.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.1)
     activemodel (3.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activemodel-3.1.0)
     simple_form (1.5.2, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/simple_form-1.5.2)
     bundler (1.0.21, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21)
     thor (0.14.6, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thor-0.14.6)
     activerecord (3.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.0)
     json (1.6.4, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/json-1.6.4)
     coffee-script (2.2.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0)
     execjs (1.2.13, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/execjs-1.2.13)
     turn (0.8.3, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/turn-0.8.3)
     rake (0.9.2.2, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2)
     kaminari (0.13.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/kaminari-0.13.0)
     rdoc (3.12, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rdoc-3.12)
     rspec (2.7.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-2.7.0)
     actionpack (3.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.1.0)
     rspec-rails (2.7.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0)
     guard (0.10.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/guard-0.10.0)
     cocoon (1.0.15, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cocoon-1.0.15)
     libv8 (3.3.10.4, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86-linux)
     rspec-core (2.7.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1)
     jquery-rails (1.0.19, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19)
     rails (3.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rails-3.1.0)
     rack-ssl (1.3.2, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.2)
     arel (2.2.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/arel-2.2.1)
     erubis (2.7.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/erubis-2.7.0)
     rb-fsevent (0.4.3.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.4.3.1)
     builder (3.0.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/builder-3.0.0)
     orm_adapter (0.0.5, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/orm_adapter-0.0.5)
     rack-cache (1.0.3, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3)
     multi_json (1.0.4, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/multi_json-1.0.4)
     spork (0.9.0.rc9, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9)
     tilt (1.3.3, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tilt-1.3.3)
     rack-mount (0.8.3, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3)
     tzinfo (0.3.31, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.31)
     validate_url (0.2.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/validate_url-0.2.0)
     sqlite3 (1.3.5, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5)
     rspec-mocks (2.7.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-mocks-2.7.0)
     polyglot (0.3.3, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/polyglot-0.3.3)
     railties (3.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.0)
     hike (1.2.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/hike-1.2.1)
     guard-spork (0.5.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/guard-spork-0.5.0)
     factory_girl_rails (1.4.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/factory_girl_rails-1.4.0)
     factory_girl (2.3.2, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/factory_girl-2.3.2)
     will_paginate (3.0.2, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/will_paginate-3.0.2)
     rack-test (0.6.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-test-0.6.1)
     client_side_validations (3.1.4, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.4)
     actionmailer (3.1.0, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0)
     bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1, file:///home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1)
```

**EDIT**

The spec_helper.rb file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'




    Spork.prefork do
      # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However, 
      # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
      # need to restart spork for it take effect.
      ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
      require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
      require 'rspec/rails'
      require 'rspec/autorun'

      # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
      # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
      Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

      RSpec.configure do |config|
        # == Mock Framework
        #
        # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
        #
        # config.mock_with :mocha
        # config.mock_with :flexmock
        # config.mock_with :rr
        config.mock_with :rspec

        # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
        config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

        # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
        # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
        # instead of true.
        config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

        # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
        # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
        # rspec-rails.
        config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
      end





    end

    Spork.each_run do
      # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
      FactoryGirl.factories.clear
      # either this if you have multiple files under 'spec/factories',
      # or just load the single file, such as 'spec/factories.rb'
      Dir.glob("#{::Rails.root}/spec/factories/*.rb").each do |file|
         load "#{file}"
      end

    end
```

Comment: Do you have a Course model defined yet?

Comment: Yes, Course is defined in app models,migrated and there is a table for it

Comment: Show more information regarding this "uninitialized constant" error please. Really really hard to debug it without it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you try to remove this line ?

```
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

I am using Factory Girl (with the factory_girl_rails gem) & Shoulda with a 3.1 project and didn't have to explicitly load definitions.

Comment: I removed FactoryGirl.find_definitions from two files:
first:
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/factory_girl_rails-1.4.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb and it worked!
second:
/home/sam/Documents/RoR/course_builder/spec/models/course_spec.rb

and it worked fine!

Comment: 5 years later - this helped me out

Answer (score 4):

All you should need to do is `require 'rspec_factory_girl'` and then the definitions.

Generally if you put it into the `spec_helper.rb`, it will require all the files in the `spec/` directory, which means if you have your factories defined for example in `spec/factories.rb`, they will get loaded automatically.

That however requires you to add `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of your spec file, which seems you're not doing.

**If you don't want to use the `spec_helper.rb` file this way, then just manually require the definition, such as `require 'factories'`.**

One little trick if you're using something like `spork` and need to reload your factories manually before each run

```
FactoryGirl.factories.clear
# either this if you have multiple files under 'spec/factories',
# or just load the single file, such as 'spec/factories.rb'
Dir.glob("#{::Rails.root}/spec/factories/*.rb").each do |file|
   load "#{file}"
end
```

**edit:** complete example of Spork

```
Spork.each_run do
  require 'factory_girl_rails'

  # reload all the models
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/*.rb"].each do |model|
    load model 
  end

  # reload all factories
  FactoryGirl.factories.clear
  Dir.glob("#{::Rails.root}/spec/factories/*.rb").each do |file|
    load "#{file}"
  end

  # reload routes
  YourAppName::Application.reload_routes!
end
```

Comment: When I put your code above in the spork starting, I get this error:

Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Factory already registered: course (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)

I wonder where the factory registered ?
I have added an edit in the question to show you the spec_helper.rb.

Comment: @SamirSabri where are you loading factory girl? It works for me when I load it in the each_run block, see edit for the whole file.

Comment: works fine, but I needed to add **FactoryGirl.sequences.clear** in addition to factories.clear, otherwise I got the DoubleDefinition Error for my custom Sequences (Mail-Adresses etc)

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error:

```
FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError: Factory already registered: factory_name
```

And I fixed the issue by adding `:require => false` in my Gemfile like this one:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
```

Then require it in the `test_helper.rb` only once by having this line:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me in Rails 4.2.6

In rails_helper.rb add these librarys

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Add these to the config part

```
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It happened when I accidentally put two factory files which contain same key as follows:

```
Rails.root/spec/factories/book.rb
Rails.root/spec/factories/books.rb
```

This is obvious, but this situation happened when I developed under no-git environment(!) and put source files by rsync(1).  When I rename book.rb to books.rb from my local PC and rsync to dev-env, both book.rb and books.rb exist and this caused the situation here;-(